# Recovering graph given degrees and connectivity information

Tags: graphs, topology

I have a graph and don't know how nodes in it are connected to each other.

- I know the number of nodes in the graph.
- I know the degree of each node in the graph.
- I know that given any node $A$ that any other node $B$ is $n$-connected (where $n$ may vary per $B$) to a sub-graph containing $A$. So if I trim $n$ specific edges edges from $B$, then $B$ won't be connected to the sub-graph containing $A$.

The question I want to know is given this information, if it's possible with high probability to learn the entire graph topology.

Comment: The word *random* has a very specific meaning in mathematics, which is different than its usual English meaning. Similarly, topology is a specific mathematical area, though I can imagine it being used for the “structure” of a graph rather than any topological properties.

Comment: One keyword sometimes used for *learning a graph* is graph reconstruction.

Comment: You want to reconstruct the graph "with high probability" — what is the probability over? Everything in your question is deterministic. Perhaps the original graph was chosen according to a specific distribution?

Comment: What do you mean when you say that $B$ is $n$-connected to a subgraph containing $A$? When is a node $n$-connected to a graph?

Comment: Maybe that's the wrong terminology. But there are `n` cuts before B and A are disjoint graphs

Comment: Do you have any other information? Consider the case when we have $k$ nodes with degree $3$, $2k + 1$ nodes of degree $1$, and you know that all nodes are $1$-connected. Then the topology can be an arbitrary tree (where inner nodes have degree $3$) you can build using these nodes. Or, another example: if all nodes have degree $2$ and you don't know anything about connectivity; then you can build an arbitrary collection of cycles.  Even if you know which nodes are connected, you can recover the cycles, but the nodes inside the cycles can be in arbitrary order.